# Как лучше всего хранить данные по 3d моделям (floatBuffer)

Tags: android, opengl

Вот у меня например из blendera `.obj` файл, после парсинга там допустим 700 вершин (float[3]), 3000 индексов `int`. Хочется их как-то сохранить в файл и потом быстро прочитать, получить floatBuffer, парсить сразу из `.obj` файла, при старте приложения мне кажется что это довольно долгая процедура. Сейчас думаю пробовать подготовить floatBuffer и сохранить их через

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("some_binary_output_file_name");
FileChannel channel = fos.getChannel();

channel.write(byteBufferBackingYourFloatBuffer);
```

Но хотелось бы понять вообще я в ту сторону думаю или не в ту и нормальные люди по другому делают? Как хранят данные по моделям, вершинам, нормалям в проектах?

Comment: Хранят чтобы за раз все прочитать и без модификаций сразу в видеокарту отдать.

Comment: Ну я в теории то понимаю что так надо, а конкретно то как это ? вот так floatBuffer записывают в файл ?

Answer (score 1):

Пока что пришел к такой схеме (оставлю тут, потому что нагуглить нормально не получилось, вдруг кому-то пригодится), для парсинга из obj использовалась вот этот проект если кому интересно https://github.com/seanrowens/oObjLoader

Сохранение в файл ( из java application , Не android )

```
String outFileName = "D:\\Dropbox\\Android\\image\\blender\\box.flt" // условно

//подготовим byteBuffer      
int bufferSize=builder.verticesG.size()*3*4;//(x,y,z)*floatSize;
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bufferSize);
byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
FloatBuffer floatBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();

floatBuffer.put(floatArray);
floatBuffer.position(0);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
FileChannel channel = fos.getChannel();

channel.write(byteBuffer);
fos.close();
```

полученный файл помещаем в assets folder.

Загрузка (Android) :

```
AssetManager assManager = context.getAssets();
InputStream is = null;
ByteBuffer pointVBB = null;
try {
        is = assManager.open(fileName);
        pointVBB = readToByteBuffer(is);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


vertextBuffer=pointVBB.asFloatBuffer();     
vertextBuffer.position(0);

//процедура получение ByteBuffera из файла.
// сразу хочу заметить что если спользовать ByteBuffer.wrap - то openGL не хочет принимать координаты, жатуется что не NativeOrder

public ByteBuffer readToByteBuffer(InputStream inStream) throws IOException {
        int bufferSize = 0x20000;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bufferSize);
        int read;
        while (true) {
          read = inStream.read(buffer);
          if (read == -1)
            break;
          outStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }               


        ByteBuffer byteData=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(outStream.size());
        byteData.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        byteData.put(outStream.toByteArray());
        //ByteBuffer byteData = ByteBuffer.wrap(outStream.toByteArray());
        byteData.position(0);

        return byteData;
      }
```

Все дальше можно vertexBuffer передавать в шейдер.